# How to "disjunctize" a uncountable family of sets

Tags: set-theory

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an uncountable family of sets. Is there a way to find another family $\{B_j\}_{j\in J}$ such that they are pairwise disjoint and $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j$?

I was looking for something similar to the countable case. If we consider the family $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, we can construct the countable family $\{B_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:

$B_1=A_1$,
$B_k=A_k\setminus (A_1\cup\dots\cup A_{k-1})$

That satisfy the conditions

Comment: Take $J=\{1\}$, $B_1=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Alternatively, take $J=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ and $B_j=\{j\}$ for $j\in J$. Presumably you want some additional conditions on the family $\{B_j\}_{j\in J}$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. My idea is to find a way to construct a family $\{B_j\}$ from family $\{A_i\}$ such that $\bigcup A_i=\bigcup B_j$ and $B_j\cap B_k=\varnothing$ for $j\neq k$

Comment: I think what @Noah is trying to say is that take $J=\bigcup A_i$ and $B_j=\{j\}$ for each $j\in J$. So you probably want to add an assumption such as $J\subseteq I$ or something else that describes some nontrivial relationship between the $A_i$ and $B_j$s.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's not what I was *trying* to say, unless I made a typo I'm not seeing that's literally what I *did* say. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No requirement that the sets be measurable?  No restriction on use of AC?  Then:
Well-order $I$, and use
$$
B_k=A_k\setminus \bigcup_{j<k} A_j\quad\text{for all } k \in I
$$

Comment: So, I guess It is necessary the Well order on $I$. Thank you very much.

Comment: That is another question.  I do not claim it is necessary to well-order $I$.  (I do not know.)  I merely claim it is sufficient to well-order $I$.

Comment: Ok. Perfect. Thank you for your time